# Export raster from QGIS 2.4 to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, export

How can I export a raster file out of QGIS (version 2.4) into a PostGIS database?

I am looking for a module or python script.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `raster2pgsql` tool which should let you to load your rasters into a PostGIS raster table.

You can also read here for more information: http://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html